# How can I push data in the background when the device reconnects to Internet

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reachability

For my app users can fill out data, save it, and have that data be pushed to the cloud (firebase to be specific). I would like users to be able to save the data when they are offline, but when the device reconnects have the data be pushed to the cloud without the user having to open up the app.

I've read a little bit about reachability and background app refresh but am not entirely sure if what I want to do is possible or how to do it if it is possible. I'm working with swift and firebase

**Update**: Is it possible to attempt to push the data every so often from the background?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. You can't run your app in the background. Yes there are background modes but they are not going to make it possible to use Reabability to wake up your app when there is a connectivity change.

Comment: And to the update: no that is not possible either.

Comment: Even with background app refresh?

Comment: Maybe depending upon your requirements, with background refresh you specify a desired time when you would like to be rescheduled. However that specifies a desire only, and the os will actually schedule when it wants to, and it might not even schedule your app to run at all.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Reachabilty](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) you can send your data when going online.

```
import ReachabilitySwift

private func setupReachability() {
    do {
        let reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
        reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            self.syncManager.syncData()
        }
        reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        dLog("Failed to start reachability")
    }
}
```

Assuming that you have persisted your data using Core Data, and when your data has been successfully sent, the rows are deleted.

Comment: But how can I do that if the app is in the background? I want it to be able to sync without the user having to open the app

Comment: Yes that is more tricky... Maybe you can schedule some local push notifications to wake the app? I don't think your app is able to listen to connectivity change while in background

Comment: There is no such thing as a local push notification. There are local notifications, which cannot wake up the app unless the user taps on them, and there are push notifications. There are no local push notifications.

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix yes I ment local notification. That can be used to remind user to open app in order to start some sync flow (if online). But I don't think it is possible to listen for connectivity change while in background and perform sync

Comment: That would work as a reminder, however when the notification fires there still may not be any connectivity.

Comment: Yes exactly, as I wrote "if online". If @BlakeGordon wants the data to be synced to server ASAP using local notification could make data sent earlier than if not using local notification as reminder. Even though it is an "poll based" behavior rather than event driven.